# django inspectdb ORA-00904 "IDENTITY_COLUMN"

Tags: python, django, database, oracle, django-models

I'm currently trying to get Django (version 2.1.5) models from existing Oracle 11 database by `python manage.py inspectdb`, but this error still occurs:

```
Unable to inspect table table_name
The error was: ORA-00904: "IDENTITY_COLUMN": invalid identifier
```

I have tried to use different Djangos. Example. with 2.0, error didn't occur, but no text for models was created. Another questions from this topic here on SO were not helpful.

Based on this [link](https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2014/09/ora-00904-invalid-identifier-error-in-11g-database.html), I think error occurs because I have no primary key in the table, but since I am not sure, I don't want to make any changes to existings database.

Does anybody solved this problem?

Comment: You can save a dump file of your database then try the solution in the link and if you  think you have messed anything you can get back the state of your database from your dump file.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and solved doing this:

```
# database configuration settings.py
#    'oracle': {
#        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.oracle',
#        'NAME': 'host:port/service',
#        'USER': 'database_user',
#        'PASSWORD': 'database_password',
#    }

    pip uninstall django
    pip install Django==1.11.22

    cd <django application>

    python manage.py inspectdb --database oracle <table name> > oraclemodel.py

    pip uninstall django
    pip install Django==2.2.4
```